# PowerShell IDE that allows editing while debugging

Tags: ide, powershell

I'm looking for a PowerShell IDE. My requirements are simple:

1. Syntax highlighting
2. Debugger
3. Ability to edit the code ***while stopped at a breakpoint***.

This last point is the problem. I've already looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171514/best-ide-for-powershell and tried **PowerShell ISE** and **PowerGUI** - both disallow this. (I've also tried **PowerShellAnalyzer**, which can only be adequately described in one word: *FAIL*)

I'm not looking for any edit-and-continue functionality. I literally just want to *not be prevented* from editing the text while stopped at a breakpoint. I'm not looking for any arguments about why this is not advisable. I just want an IDE that allows it.

Comment: There is a software suite that fits the requirements, more or less. All pieces are open source. The suite is **very different from classic PowerShell IDEs**, something is worse, something is better, but most of things are not really comparable. It is powerful but its adoption is challenging. My SO profile has a link to it. If you are interested, I will provide the answer with details. Note: editing of a script being debugged is possible right now but this scenario should be slightly improved, I can do that, it looks useful.

Comment: Thoughts. After a change the core continues execution of the **old** code for a while. What code should the debugger UI step through: the old or new? Probably the **old**, otherwise this is a mess. Then, when the entire script is called again the core loads and executes the **new** code. The debugger UI has to switch to the **new** code at this point. Not sure, it is technically possible; it’s tricky in any case.

Comment: Another challenge is line breakpoints in the script being modified during execution. They are still valid for the old code being executed for a while but then they become potentially invalid when the script in the same run is called again. To resolve this properly is difficult. I’ll eventually think of this feature in my host and debugger but I am starting to have some doubts.

Comment: Yes, those are serious challenges, that's why I'd be OK with the debugger just ignoring the changes and running the old code. In fact, most of the time I'm going to restart anyway, but I want to edit the code first, *then* restart.

Comment: Do you know [**NetBeans**](http://netbeans.org/)? It recently added support for it, but I don't know what the _state of the art is_.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerSE](http://powerwf.com/products/powerse.aspx) can edit scripts while stopped at a breakpoint.

I know it's not an issue for you as you said, but you can continue stepping through the script, but it executes the old code so the position marker no longer lines up with the code being executed.